# Python 3.6.2 Proofpoint Decoder IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Proofpoint has a simple Python script that decodes URL's that have been rewritten. This was written and published by them so I was assuming it would work. Could this be a Python 2.7 vs. 3.x.x thing? I am trying to run it in Pycharms right now to run it.

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/PP-Decoder.py", line 10, in main
    rewrittenurl = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code:

```
#!python

import sys
import re
import urllib.parse
import html.parser


def main():
    rewrittenurl = sys.argv[1]
    match = re.search(r'https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/(v[0-9])/', rewrittenurl)
    if match:
        if match.group(1) == 'v1':
            decodev1(rewrittenurl)
        elif match.group(1) == 'v2':
            decodev2(rewrittenurl)
        else:
            print('Unrecognized version in: ', rewrittenurl)

    else:
        print('No valid URL found in input: ', rewrittenurl)


def decodev1(rewrittenurl):
    match = re.search(r'u=(.+?)&k=', rewrittenurl)
    if match:
        urlencodedurl = match.group(1)
        htmlencodedurl = urllib.parse.unquote(urlencodedurl)
        url = html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape(htmlencodedurl)
        print(url)
    else:
        print('Error parsing URL')


def decodev2(rewrittenurl):
    match = re.search(r'u=(.+?)&[dc]=', rewrittenurl)
    if match:
        specialencodedurl = match.group(1)
        trans = str.maketrans('-_', '%/')
        urlencodedurl = specialencodedurl.translate(trans)
        htmlencodedurl = urllib.parse.unquote(urlencodedurl)
        url = html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape(htmlencodedurl)
        print(url)
    else:
        print('Error parsing URL')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note: In later versions, 'html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape() should just be 'html.unescape()'...with just 'import html'

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I think it's cause it's running without an argument.